# Create a list of disposable emails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm sending emails with asp.net core 2.0 like this

```
 public string EmailServiceSend(string body, string subject = null, string to = null,
                string multipleRecipients = null, string attachmentUrl = null, string smtpClient = null,
                string userCredential = null, string userPassword = null, string from = null, bool template = false,
                string templateRoute = null)
              {
try
        {
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mysmtpserver");
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("whoever@me.com");
    mailMessage.To.Add("receiver@me.com");
    mailMessage.Body = body;
    mailMessage.Subject = subject;
    client.Send(mailMessage);
 }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Message.ToString();
        }

    return "Email sended"
             }
```

I want to know, how can I create a list of email domains to block and send an error message. For example I want to block this domains:

```
0-mail.com
0815.ru
0clickemail.com
0wnd.net
```

and then send a response into my `return` statement for example:

```
if(listofblockmails == true){
 return "You can't add this email domain, change it please"
    }
```

How can I achieve that? Regards

Comment: Parse the email address and get only the domain part and compare against your black list and return as needed. What is the trouble you are facing in implementing this ?

Comment: I don't know how can I made list.. into method like `public string blacklist(){}`? and when I have method how can I call it, can you show me an example of this_ @Shyju

Comment: Where is your `email domain` ? It is not a parameter to your method!

Comment: In case you want to delegate this to a service, I created https://www.validator.pizza. So you just have to do an GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Linq:

Lets say you have this List:

```
List<string> listofblockmails = new List<string>();
listofblockmails.Add("0-mail.com");
listofblockmails.Add("0815.ru");
listofblockmails.Add("0clickemail.com");
listofblockmails.Add("0wnd.net");
```

You can do as below:

```
if (listofblockmails.Contains("emailToBeChecked.com"))
{
    //return "You can't add this email domain, change it please";
}
else
{
    //send
    //return "Email sended";
}
```

And let Garbage collector do the disposal.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply parse the email address and get the domain part, and compare againist a list of bad domains. If the domain is present in your bad domain list, return messge.

You can create a method like this.

```
private bool IsGoodDomain(string email)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        return false;

    var badDomains = new List<string>
    {
        "0815.ru",
        "0wnd.net"
    };
    var r = email.Split('@');
    if (!r.Any()) return false;
    var domainName = r.Last();
    return !badDomains.Contains(domainName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

and call this method in your other method

```
if(IsGoodDomain(someEmailAddressVariable))
{
  //contnue sending
}
else
{
  // return the error message
}
```